# How to access video streaming site using proxy

Tags: proxy

IS there any proxy site or trick which can be helpful to open blocked sites . I can access site using anonymouse.org and other sites but a site which have some video don't work . Is there any way .

Comment: It would depend on the specific video streaming site and why it is blocked for you.

Comment: Use VPN service it's more easy to handle videos, "security kiss" for example it's for free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what kind of blocking you're talking about.

If you're on a business trip behind the Great Firewall of China and trying to get to some video streaming that is lawful for you in all relevant jurisdictions but is blocked as part of a global rule, then your simplest bet is to use a VPN client on the computer you have there, and connect to a VPN server here.

In this case, if you use OpenVPN, for example, be very sure to use a TA key as well; a key that protects even the initial connection setup.

If you're at work, stop trying to get to blocked sites on the sly.

Be aware of the legal issues before you start, as well.